# docs on Airtable filterByFormula

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, airtable

I'm trying to do some simple filters on Airtable API queries, and getting `INVALID_FILTER_BY_FORMULA` errors. I can't find much docs on this.

How can I do an `AND` type filter?

All the below are failing!

```
    filter: "NOT({imageStatus}='rejected' "
    // filter: "NOT({name} = '')"
    // filter: "{status} = 'test-1' AND {renderStatus} = NOT('OK') }",
    // filter: "NOT ({renderStatus} = 'OK') ",
    // filter: "{renderStatus} = NOT('OK')",
```

update: found out a not is simply `{status} != 'none'`

but any other cheat sheet examples would be nice

AT docs are very poor on this:

- https://support.airtable.com/docs/how-to-sort-filter-or-retrieve-ordered-records-in-the-api
- https://support.airtable.com/docs/formula-field-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the records from 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' where the {status} field is equal to 'test-1' AND the {renderStatus} field is not equal to 'OK'. You can also use the "!=" operator instead of "NOT" to indicate "not equal to".

```
const Airtable = require('airtable');
const base = new Airtable({ apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY' }).base('YOUR_BASE_ID');

base('YOUR_TABLE_NAME').select({
  filterByFormula: "AND({status} = 'test-1', {renderStatus} != 'OK')"
}).firstPage((err, records) => {
  if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
  records.forEach(record => {
    console.log('Retrieved', record.get('name'));
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks! btw how do i specify `{field} = "" ` undefined/null/empty? i was trying the quotes but i think that only works for string fields.

Comment: Anytime. You can use the BLANK() function. Let say you want to filter records where the field is empty. `base('Table Name').select({
  filterByFormula: "BLANK({field})"
}).firstPage((err, records) => {
  if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
  console.log(records);
});`

Comment: do you work for them or... how did you figure these out? i guess you can try formulas just in the main view but ..

Comment: No, I'm still novice, just learning. I study Airtable by helping and reading solutions on Airtable Community. For JS scripting, it's  airscript.dev / Sololearn. By attempting to troubleshoot other users, I get to read technical documentation and keep learning while helping. If that can be helpful, here is a website I use to learn: https://www.airscript.dev/about